# How can I filter an array by its properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have a headless CMC WP that's fetched into my Javascript and stored. I want to filter it by a property(*if the property value = to the value I input in html then it should append  to the innerHTML*) and therefore I tried to loop through it but it does not work.
This is my function:

```
for (let i in this.filtered) {
  for (let y in this.filtered[i].categories) {
    //console.log(this.filtered[i].categories[y] + " ");
    const results = this.filtered[i].categories[y].filter(post => post == value)
    console.log(results);
  }
}
```

It says in the console that `this.filtered[i].categories[y].filter` is not a function.

this is a part of the array from `this.filtered`, I want to filter by categories.
[image]

This is what it shows when I console.log(this.filtered[i].categories[y]);
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Before using the function `filter` try console.log `this.filtered[i].categories[y]` and edit your answer by adding the result at the end of your text, that's help you get more quickly an answer. We know for sure it's not an array so maybe it's undefined, null, (a string maybe?)

Comment: Arrays don't have properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It says in the console that `this.filtered[i].categories[y].filter` is not a function.

The items in the `categories` array, according to your screenshot, are simple integers. Integers don’t understand/implement any method called `filter()`. (Put another way: what would you do if I told you to filter the number 7?) Logically, it’s clear that this is not what you intended.

While you’re headed down the right path, I’d recommend you keep it simple: run `Array.filter` on your outermost array and use the logic in the callback to test whether the `categories` sub-array contains the value you’re looking for:

```js
var _this = {};
_this.filtered = [{
    acf: {},
    author: 1,
    categories: [18, 2, 3]
  },
  {
    acf: {},
    author: 2,
    categories: [4, 3, 7, 18]
  }
];

const value = 2;

var filteredResults = _this.filtered.filter(cv => cv.categories.includes(value));

console.log(filteredResults);
```

Comment: when I console.log(filteredResults) it still shows an empty array.

Comment: Does any of your data in `this.filtered` contain any objects that match the criteria? Can you confirm `value` is properly set using the input you mention in your question? Finally, can you update your question so it contains sample values for both `this.filtered` and `value` so that it conforms to our guidance on creating a [mre]?

Comment: @Marcel I've added a complete working example to my answer, which works as expected. Can you elaborate on how your code differs from the example?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not see the comment; It works now, it did not work because I was looping through a wrong array that differed a bit. Thank you for your response!